# Filling Colors inside edges

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to Iphone development.

Currently i am making coloring app.

I am using apple's paint app as ref to create my app.

I successfully create app where u can color on a screen with given texture image

What i did is
I create a custom UIView which extends opengl and i detect touches on it and draw accordingly.
I also kept background UIImageView which contain outline images, so it feels like your drawing above that Image.

Everything works fine
but i wanted to fill color inside black edges

Like if a image has four square which has black edges and inside of that square is blank and if i touch any square it should fill that square with selected color(mostly i am working on irregular shape)

Can anyone tell me how can i fill colors inside that square

The flood fill algo looks slow as i have some big images which will take time to fill the color

so is there any easy method by which i can fill color

A sample code will b very helpful as i am new to iPhone Dev

Answer (score 1):

I implemnted this kind of feature in my recent project. The difference is: I filled color in border only.

Check my code over here, it might get helpful to you

```
    // apply color to only border & return an image
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    // load the image
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}
```

Enjoy Programming !

Comment: In the eg that i gave I have all those four square inside a single image
So i need to detect each square(remember i said i am working on irregular shape)
So how can i detect those part
Do i need to use CGpath to draw those shapes??

Comment: yes this will detect border for irregular shape also. this is definitely not for you to fill color inside the shape, I repeat this is for coloring only border/frame. But you can get an idea to achieve your desires using this. Just go through it once